# How to merge two data sets using common field and using transform s with the help of elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch, elk, elasticsearch-transform

Using transforms in elasticsearch how to merge two datasets if the have same field for example

**Table A**

```
id name
1  a
2  b
```

**Table B**

```
id name
1  c
3  d
```

If both the ids are same then merge the datas in new table using transforms

Comment: These are the RDBMS tables, which are the source and that you want to execute join operation prior to indexing them in Elasticsearch. Could you clarify if that is what you are trying to do?